# Sonarcloud giving uncovered lines for interface

Tags: sonarqube, sonarcloud

I added an optional parameter to a method in C# interface. The method was already existing and I just modified to add an optional parameter. I have added the unit tests and all are passing. But the SonarCloud is showing uncovered lines just for interface. For the implementation class it is giving full coverage. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you share the code of your interface?